# Permission error on upload with blueimp jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have a problem with the jQuery-File-Upload. I'm using it with PHP code and I would to upload the file in different folder based on the logged user.
For example if the logged user has code 'abcd', I would to upload the file in 'upload/2017/abcd/'.

To do this I wrote this code:

```
$(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
        var url = 'upload/<?= $year?>/<?= $logged_user?>';
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            upload_dir: url,
            upload_url: url,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
```

The folders exists, and has the correct permission (0777), but when I try to upload, I have this error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /upload/2017/abcd/ on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: There is folder ( 2017 ) AND ( abcd ) in folder upload ?

Comment: Yes I already wrote that "the folders exists"

Comment: for test permission (upload, 2017, abcd) to 0777 .

Comment: `chmod -R 0777 upload` will change all the directories and sub directories like 2017, abcd etc and makes accessible for any user/Group to make changes to directory.

for windows: right click on the folder and change permission

Comment: I'm just trying it! Maybe I can upload file only on a set folder and I can't change dynamically....

Comment: @Swim89 did you ever solve this? Where is the PHP that handles the upload? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options):

> ### url
>
> A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

This should be an upload handler, eg a PHP script, which will do the work of validating, naming, and moving the files into place.  The code you show above even includes a comment saying the same thing:

```
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
```

But it looks like you are using url to specify a target directory to save files in:

```
var url = 'upload/<?= $year?>/<?= $logged_user?>';
```

The blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload distribution [includes a set of PHP files](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php) for the server-side implementation, it looks like `index.php` is supposed to be the one you should point `url` at.  I am not familiar with the plugin or the back end handler, but looking through the source I can see where the upload directory is specified, [on line 47](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php#L47):

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
```

That is one place you could do your `year/user/` directory customisation.

As to why you are seeing the `403 Forbidden` error: as you've specified a directory as the `url`, that's where `fileupload` will POST the files.  Your `url` has no trailing slash (`upload/2017/abcd`), and [Apache will forward that](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) - as a GET - to the same directory *with* the trailing slash.  Since there is no suitable index file in the directory to handle the request (no `index.html`, `index.php`, and/or whatever you have configured as [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) in Apache), Apache will attempt to do a directory listing.  However you have directory listing disabled ([`Options -Indexes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options)), so you get a `403 Forbidden`.  You should be able to verify all this by looking in your browser devtools, clicking the Network tab, and examining the requests there.

As a side note, you are specifying `upload_dir` and `upload_url` options for the `fileupload()` in your Javascript, but those are variables in the back-end PHP handler I linked to above.  They're PHP variables, and won't have any effect in your Javascript, you should remove them to avoid confusion.